# Unit testing controller triggering custom directive

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine, angularjs-controller

Suppose you have an angular+jasmine app and your controller looks something like this:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
   $scope.myFunc = function() {
   $scope.myArray = [];
       // after some operations here
       myArray.push(new_obj);
   }
   $scope.someOtherArray = [];
}
```

Additionally, I have a custom directive that is triggered by every element in `myArray`. Something like this:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
         // directive goes here
         // and some definitions
         link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
               scope.someOtherArray.push(other_obj)
         }
    }
}
```

and finally, in the HTML:

```
<div myDirective ng-repeat="obj in myArray"></div>
```

So, every time I add an element to `myArray`, another directive element is created and `$scope.someOtherArray` is modified. That works pretty well, but I found that `myFunc()` and the properties of the controller are difficult to test:

```
controller = $controller('MyController', { $scope: mockScope });
SpyOn(mockScope, 'myFunc').and.callThrough();
// expectGET and expectPOST here.
mockScope.myFunc();
```

However, after running that code, there were some objects (dependent on the custom directive) that were not being updated after calling `mockScope.myFunc();` (such as `someOtherArray`). Apparently, I need to compile the custom directives manually:

```
var element = '<div myDirective ng-repeat="obj in myArray"></div>';
element = $compile(element)(mockScope);
```

Well, that seems a bit awkward. I was expecting that after running `mockScope.myFunc()` every side effect would take place automatically. Otherwise, I need to consider every directive involved in the process and compile each of them.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I you wan to test the `myFunc` function just test if `myArray` increments appropriately. And create a different `describe` for the directive where you will take care of compiling it and check all its resposabilities.

Comment: Sure, that's what I did. But do I need to compile each directive separately?

Comment: I added more details to the question. Maybe that gives a better idea of what I intended to do.